# Disabling @mention of a public group by certain profiles only in Chatter Salesforce

Tags: chatter, profile, public-group, chatter-groups

Is it possible to disable @mention of a public group in any post or comment by regular users ?

Only particular profiles should be able to @mention the public group name.

Please suggest.

Comment: Code or Configuration, anyway if its possible, it will be good.

Comment: A use case would be helpful to understand the issue you're trying to solve. A naive opinion might be that if you've made the group public then you want people to see it. If you want people to see it then you want people to be able to interact with it. @mention is a the lightweight, flexible way to interact.

Answer (score 2):

You can do one thing. Write trigger on **feeditem** and get body of message then you can check if string contains you group name and profile is not matched. Then add error message. using `trigger.New[0].addError();`

Answer (score 0):

There's also a new type of group called [Broadcast Groups](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_chatter_groups_broadcast.htm?edition=&impact=) that restricts group posts and @mentions to the group owner and group managers. It's being [piloted](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_chatter_groups_broadcast.htm?edition=&impact=) in Winter '16 and will be generally available in Spring '16.

It doesn't have profile-based restrictions, although you could write some code to allow all users with a given profile to become group managers.